# How can I create JDBC auth with Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security

I am having problems to create a project with a simple authentication using JDBC. I have found many examples with Spring Boot 2, but none with Spring Boot 3.

I tried the [Spring documentation itself](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/jdbc.html), but I have difficulties to understand the steps without seeing the folder structure of a project.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: With "Spring 3", do you mean a very old version of the core Spring Framework or do you mean Spring Boot 3, the latest version of Spring Boot? As far as I know, there is no big difference between Spring Boot 2 and Spring Boot 3 with regard to this, so the examples you have for Spring Boot 2 should still be useable.

Comment: Spring Boot 3, sorry, I will edit the question. The problem is that I am having many "deprecated" issues if I simply copy and paste the code from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3, and it is not clear for me how to replace it.

One example is, in Spring Boot 3, I am unable to use `csrf` nor to get it working.